# Why wont my array average all numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

i have to create an array and a method call for the average. but for some reason it is not average all numbers, its only returning the last number. I have asked my instructor for help and she said the math is correct it should work. But no other help from her. What have I done wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] myArray = new double[2];

    initialize(myArray);
    double avg = getAverage(myArray);
    System.out.println(avg);
    output(avg);
}

public static void initialize(double[] myArray) {
    //myArray = new double[1000];
    for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i] = (int) ((Math.random()*500)*1);
        System.out.println(myArray[i]);
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param myArray
 * @return
 */
public static double getAverage(double[] myArray) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        sum += myArray[i];
    }
    return sum / myArray.length;
}

public static void output(double avg) {
    System.out.println("The average is " + avg);
}
```

Comment: You're doing integer division.

Comment: Please add an example of the expected output vs. the actual output you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is in this line:

```
sum / myArray.length
```

...since both `sum` and `myArray.length` are integers, Java performs integer division, not floating point division, which essentially means it drops the decimal component of the result.

Casting one of the values to a `double` first will force a floating point division to occur.

You're also storing the sum as an int, which could again introduce a source of error since the array contains doubles. In this case you're ok because you're casting everything you put into the array to an int first, which begs the question as to why you're using a double array in the first place?

As an aside, this is a bit odd:

```
((Math.random()*500)*1);
```

There's no need to multiply the result by 1 here - that won't do anything.

Comment: My instructor asked for a double array, thats the reason. Also she is the one who told us to use the math.random multiplied by one. Im not kidding either. Im losing more and more confidence in her abilities. I think that's why she couldn't help me. The problem im having is its only returning the last number. it should be averaging all. According to her instructions she wants us to use the math.random then average them in a method. Is there anyway to accomplish this with double?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem here? The answers are coming correctly. Please check again. The interesting fact is that the third number is always same as the average of all three. But the average computation is correct. That may be how Math.random() generates random numbers internally. The third is the average of the other two. Try out four or five numbers instead of three numbers and check your answers.